# Set selected state on navbar according to URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm sort of new to react.js and having trouble figureing this out...

I want a Navbar that displays which page you are on (in this example if you are on page A or B). In this case this is done by a state controlling the “selected” param in the "ListItemButton".

Page A and B are nested inside the Nav and are displayed by the "Outlet" (see App.js).

Nav.jsx:

```
import { List, ListItemButton } from '@mui/material'
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Nav = () => {

    navigate = useNavigate()

    const [pageASelected, setPageASelected] = React.useState()
    const [pageBSelected, setPageBSelected] = React.useState()

    const handlePageA = () => {
        setPageASelected(true)
        setPageBSelected(false)
        navigate('a')
    }

    const handlePageB = () => {
        setPageASelected(false)
        setPageBSelected(true)
        navigate('ab')
    }

  return (
    <List>
        <ListItemButton selected={pageASelected} onClick={handlePageA}>Page A</ListItemButton>
        <ListItemButton selected={pageBSelected} onClick={handlePageA}>Page b</ListItemButton>
        <Outlet/>
    </List>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

App.js:

```
<Route path='/' element={<Nav/>}>
    <Route path='a' element={<PageA/>}/>
    <Route path='b' element={<PageB/>}/>
</Route>
```

This setup will handle the "selected" state when i navigate inside the application, but on a page refresh and back button click it will either reset the state or not update it...

I know this is probably the wrong way of doing this, so how would you guys recommend I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `NavLink` component provided by React Router to use in your `Nav` component. You can conditionally assign a style to it if its the active/current route.

Your `App` component should be something like this:

```js
<>
  <Nav>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/a' element={<PageA/>}/>
      <Route path='/b' element={<PageB/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</>
```

Your `Nav` component should be similar to this:

```js
  <header>
    <nav>
     <ul>
       <li>
          <NavLink
            to="/a"
            className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? 'active-route-class' : 'inactive-route-class }
          >
            A
          </NavLink>
       </li>
       <li>
        <NavLink
          to="/b"
          className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? 'active-route-class' : 'inactive-route-class }
          >
            B
          </NavLink>
       </li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```